# Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: wordpress

here is the error i get on my website when trying to process a payment page am not sure what to do i found this code

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/bargainhivee/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1482) in /home/bargainhivee/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Tevolution/tmplconnector/templatic-connector.php on line 5
```

this is the line 5

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
```

here is the php file templatic-connector.php

```
<?php
    /*
    * includes the main files of tevolution default ad-on such as claim ownership,custom taxonomy,csutom fields,etc. and common functions.
    */
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

    require_once(TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH."/templatic-claim_ownership/install.php" ); 
    require_once(TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH."/templatic-custom_taxonomy/install.php" );
    require_once(TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH."/templatic-custom_fields/install.php" );
    require_once(TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH."/templatic-monetization/install.php" );
    require_once(TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH."/templatic-ratings/install.php" );
    require_once(TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH."/templatic-registration/install.php" );
    require_once (TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH . "/templatic-widgets/templatic_browse_by_categories_widget.php");         
    require_once (TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH . "/templatic-widgets/templatic_advanced_search_widget.php");          
    require_once (TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH . "/templatic-widgets/templatic_people_list_widget.php");          
    require_once (TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH . "/templatic-widgets/templatic_metakey_search_widget.php");           

    require_once(TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH."templatic-generalization/general_functions.php" );

    /* Add to favourites for tevolution*/
    if(file_exists(TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH."templatic-generalization/add_to_favourites.php") && (!strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/wp-admin/') || strstr

    ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/admin-ajax.php') )){
        require_once(TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH."templatic-generalization/add_to_favourites.php" );
    }

    /*
     do action for admin menu
    */
    add_action('admin_menu', 'templ_add_admin_menu_'); /* create templatic admin menu */
    function templ_add_admin_menu_()
    {
        do_action('templ_add_admin_menu_');
    }


    add_action('templ_add_admin_menu_', 'templ_add_mainadmin_menu_', 0);
    add_action('templ_add_admin_menu_', 'templ_remove_mainadmin_sub_menu_');
    if(!function_exists('templ_remove_mainadmin_sub_menu_')){
        function templ_remove_mainadmin_sub_menu_(){
            remove_submenu_page('templatic_system_menu', 'templatic_system_menu'); 
            add_submenu_page( 'templatic_system_menu', __('Overview','templatic-admin'), __('Overview','templatic-admin'), 'administrator', 

    'templatic_system_menu', 'templatic_connector_class' );
        }
    }
    /*
     include the main.connector.class.php file
    */
    function templatic_connector_class()
    {
         require_once(TEVOLUTION_PAGE_TEMPLATES_DIR.'classes/main.connector.class.php' );   
    }
    /*
        Return the main menu at admin sidebar
    */
    function templ_add_mainadmin_menu_()
    {
        $menu_title = __('Tevolution', 'templatic');
        if (function_exists('add_object_page'))
        {
            if(isset($_REQUEST['page']) && $_REQUEST['page'] == 'templatic_system_menu'){
                $icon = TEMPL_PLUGIN_URL.'favicon-active.png';
            }else{
                $icon = TEMPL_PLUGIN_URL.'favicon-active.png';
            }
            $hook = add_menu_page("Admin Menu", $menu_title, 'administrator', 'templatic_system_menu', 'dashboard_bundles', '',3); /* title of new 

    sidebar*/
        }else{
            add_menu_page("Admin Menu", $menu_title, 'administrator',  'templatic_wp_admin_menu', 'design','');     
        } 
    }
    /*
     return the connection with dashboard wizards(bundle box)
    */
    function dashboard_bundles()
    {
        $Templatic_connector = New Templatic_connector;
        require_once(TEVOLUTION_PAGE_TEMPLATES_DIR.'classes/main.connector.class.php' );    
        if(isset($_REQUEST['tab']) && $_REQUEST['tab'] =='extend') {    
            $Templatic_connector->templ_extend();
        }else if(isset($_REQUEST['tab']) && $_REQUEST['tab'] =='payment-gateways') {    
            $Templatic_connector->templ_payment_gateway();
        }else if((!isset($_REQUEST['tab'])&& @$_REQUEST['tab']=='') || isset($_REQUEST['tab']) && $_REQUEST['tab'] =='overview') {  
            $Templatic_connector->templ_overview();
            $Templatic_connector->templ_dashboard_extends();
        }

    }

    /*
     return main CSS of Plugin
    */
    add_action('admin_head', 'templ_add_my_stylesheet'); /* include style sheet */
    add_action('wp_head', 'templ_add_my_stylesheet',0); /* include style sheet */   

    function templ_add_my_stylesheet()
    {

      /* Respects SSL, Style.css is relative to the current file */
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        $tmpl_is_allow_url_fopen = tmpl_is_allow_url_fopen();

        /* Tevolution Plug-in Style Sheet File In Desktop view only  */ 
        if (function_exists('tmpl_wp_is_mobile') && !tmpl_wp_is_mobile()) {

            /* if "allow_url_fopen" is enabled then apply minifiled css otherwise includse seperately */
            if(!$tmpl_is_allow_url_fopen){
                wp_enqueue_style('tevolution_style',TEMPL_PLUGIN_URL.'style.css','',false);
            }else{
                wp_enqueue_style('tevolution_style',TEMPL_PLUGIN_URL.'css.minifier.php','',false);
            }
        }
        if(function_exists('theme_get_settings')){
            if(theme_get_settings('supreme_archive_display_excerpt')){
                if(function_exists('tevolution_excerpt_length')){
                    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'tevolution_excerpt_length');
                }
                if(function_exists('new_excerpt_more')){
                    add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* check if "allow_url_fopen" is enabled or not */
    function tmpl_is_allow_url_fopen(){
        if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }   

    /*
    return each add-ons is activated or not
    */
    function is_active_addons($key)
    {
      $act_key = get_option($key);
      if ($act_key != '')
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    /*
     Function will remove the admin dashboard widget
    */
    function templ_remove_dashboard_widgets()
    {
      /* Globalize the metaboxes array, this holds all the widgets for wp-admin*/
      global $wp_meta_boxes;
      /* Remove the Dashboard quickpress widget*/
      unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']);
      /* Remove the Dashboard  incoming links widget*/
      unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_incoming_links']);
      /* Remove the Dashboard secondary widget*/
      unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary']);
    }
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'templ_remove_dashboard_widgets');

    /* -- coding to add submenu under main menu-- */
    add_action('templ_add_admin_menu_', 'templ_add_page_menu');
    function templ_add_page_menu()
    {

        /*tevolution_menu_before_general_settings hook for add additional menu before general settings */
        do_action('tevolution_menu_before_general_settings');

        $menu_title2 = __('Settings', 'templatic-admin');
        add_submenu_page('templatic_system_menu', $menu_title2, $menu_title2,'administrator', 'templatic_settings', 'my_page_templates_function');

        /*tevolution_menu_after_general_settings hook for add additional menu after general settings */
        do_action('tevolution_menu_after_general_settings');        
    }

    /*
        Email, security , and set up steps menu selected
     */
    add_action('admin_footer','tevolution_menu_script');
    function tevolution_menu_script()
    {
        ?>
        <script  data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" async >
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
              if(jQuery('#adminmenu ul.wp-submenu li').hasClass('current'))
              {
                   <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['page']) && $_REQUEST['page']=='templatic_system_menu' && isset($_REQUEST['tab']) && $_REQUEST['tab']=='setup-steps' 

    ):?>
                   jQuery('#adminmenu ul.wp-submenu li').removeClass('current');
                   jQuery('#adminmenu ul.wp-submenu li a').removeClass('current');                              
                   jQuery('#adminmenu ul.wp-submenu li a[href*="page=templatic_system_menu&tab=setup-steps"]').attr('href', function() {                


                            jQuery('#adminmenu ul.wp-submenu li a[href*="page=templatic_system_menu&tab=setup-steps"]').addClass('current');
                            jQuery('#adminmenu ul.wp-submenu li a[href*="page=templatic_system_menu&tab=setup-steps"]').parent().addClass('current');
                   });
                   <?php endif;?>

              }
              jQuery('.reset_custom_fields').click( function() {
                   if(confirm("<?php echo __('All your modifications done with this, will be deleted forever! Still you want to proceed?','templatic-admin');?

    >")){
                        return true;
                   }else{
                        return false;
                   }    
              });
         });
         </script>
         <?php
    }

    /* include general_settings.php file */
    function my_page_templates_function()
    {   
        include(TEMPL_MONETIZE_FOLDER_PATH.'templatic-generalization/general_settings.php');

    }

    /*
        Redirect on plugin dashboard after activating plugin
    */
    add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_redirect');
    function my_plugin_redirect()
    {  
        global $pagenow;    
        if (get_option('myplugin_redirect_on_first_activation') == 'true' && $pagenow=='plugins.php' ){
            update_option('myplugin_redirect_on_first_activation', 'false');
            wp_redirect(MY_PLUGIN_SETTINGS_URL);
        }
        if (get_option('myplugin_redirect_on_first_activation') == 'true' && $pagenow=='themes.php' ){
            update_option('myplugin_redirect_on_first_activation', 'false');
            wp_redirect(site_url().'/wp-admin/themes.php');
        }
    }

    /*
     * View counter for detail page
     */
    function view_counter_single_post($pid){    
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == '' || !strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
        {
            $viewed_count = get_post_meta($pid,'viewed_count',true);
            $viewed_count_daily = get_post_meta($pid,'viewed_count_daily',true);
            $daily_date = get_post_meta($pid,'daily_date',true);

            update_post_meta($pid,'viewed_count',$viewed_count+1);
        if(get_post_meta($pid,'daily_date',true) == date('Y-m-d')){
                update_post_meta($pid,'viewed_count_daily',$viewed_count_daily+1);
            } else {
                update_post_meta($pid,'viewed_count_daily','1');
            }
            update_post_meta($pid,'daily_date',date('Y-m-d'));
        }
    }

    /*
     * return the count of post view 
     */
    if(!function_exists('user_single_post_visit_count')){
    function user_single_post_visit_count($pid)
    {
        if(get_post_meta($pid,'viewed_count',true))
        {
            return get_post_meta($pid,'viewed_count',true);
        }else
        {
            return '0'; 
        }
    }
    }
    /*
     * Function Name:user_single_post_visit_count_daily
     * Argument: Post id
     */
    if(!function_exists('user_single_post_visit_count_daily')){
    function user_single_post_visit_count_daily($pid)
    {
        if(get_post_meta($pid,'viewed_count_daily',true))
        {
            return get_post_meta($pid,'viewed_count_daily',true);
        }else
        {
            return '0'; 
        }
    }
    }
    /*
     * add view count display after the content
     */
    if( !function_exists('view_count')){
    function view_count( $content ) {   

        if ( is_single()) 
        {
            global $post;
            $sep =" , ";
            $custom_content='';
            $custom_content.="<p>".__('Visited','templatic')." ".user_single_post_visit_count($post->ID)." ".__('times','templatic');
            $custom_content.= $sep.user_single_post_visit_count_daily($post->ID).__(" Visits today",'templatic')."</p>";
            $custom_content .= $content;
            echo $custom_content;
        } 
    }
    }
    /*
     * show counter and share button after custom fields.
     */
    function teamplatic_view_counter()
    {
       $settings = get_option( "templatic_settings" );      
       if(isset($settings['templatic_view_counter']) && $settings['templatic_view_counter']=='Yes')
       {    
            global $post;
            view_counter_single_post($post->ID);
            view_count('');
       }  
       //view_sharing_buttons('');
       tevolution_socialmedia_sharelink();

    }

    /*Remove the  the_content filter to add view counter everywhere in single page and add action tmpl_detail_page_custom_fields_collection before the custom 

    field display*/

    add_action('tmpl_detail_page_custom_fields_collection','teamplatic_view_counter',5);
    function view_sharing_buttons($content)
    {
        global $post;   
        if (is_single() && ($post->post_type!='post' && $post->post_type!='page'  && $post->post_type!='product'   && $post->post_type!='product_variation' 

    )) 
        {
            $post_img = bdw_get_images_plugin($post->ID,'thumb');
            $post_images = $post_img[0];
            $title=urlencode($post->post_title);
            $url=urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID));
            $summary=urlencode(htmlspecialchars($post->post_content));
            $image=$post_images;
            $settings = get_option( "templatic_settings" );

            if($settings['facebook_share_detail_page'] =='yes' || $settings['google_share_detail_page'] == 'yes' || $settings

    ['twitter_share_detail_page'] == 'yes' || $settings['pintrest_detail_page']=='yes'){
            echo '<div class="share_link">';
                if($settings['facebook_share_detail_page'] == 'yes')
                  {
                    ?>
                    <a onClick="window.open('//www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo 

    $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" 

    href="javascript: void(0)" id="facebook_share_button"><?php _e('Facebook Share.',T_DOMAIN); ?></a>
                    <?php
                  }
                if($settings['google_share_detail_page'] == 'yes'): ?>
                    <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
                    <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div> 
                <?php endif;

                if($settings['twitter_share_detail_page'] == 'yes'): ?>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-text='<?php echo htmlentities

    ($post->post_content);?>' data-url="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" data-counturl="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php _e

    ('Tweet',T_DOMAIN); ?></a>
                        <script data-cfasync="false">!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id))

    {js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-

    wjs");</script>
                <?php endif;

                if(@$settings['pintrest_detail_page']=='yes'):?>
                   <!-- Pinterest -->
                   <div class="pinterest"> 
                        <a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;media=<?php echo $image; ?

    >&amp;description=<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php _e('Pin It','templatic');?></a>
                        <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>                    
                   </div>
                   <?php endif; 
            echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        return $content;
    }

    /*
        return the currency code 
    */
    function templatic_get_currency_type()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $option_value = get_option('currency_code');
        if($option_value)
        {
            return stripslashes($option_value);
        }else
        {
            return 'USD';
        }

    }
    /* 
        this function returns the currency with position selected in currency settings 
    */
    function fetch_currency_with_position($amount,$currency = '')
    {
        $amt_display = '';
        if($amount==''){ $amount =0; }
        $decimals=get_option('tmpl_price_num_decimals');
        $decimals=($decimals!='')?$decimals:2;
        if($amount >=0 )
        {
            if(@$amount !='')
                $amount = number_format( (float)($amount),$decimals,'.','');
                $currency = get_option('currency_symbol');
                $position = get_option('currency_pos');
            if($position == '1')
            {
                $amt_display = $currency.$amount;
            }
            else if($position == '2')
            {
                $amt_display = $currency.' '.$amount;
            }
            else if($position == '3')
            {
                $amt_display = $amount.$currency;
            }
            else
            {
                $amt_display = $amount.' '.$currency;
            }
            return apply_filters('tmpl_price_format',$amt_display,$amount,$currency);
        }
    }

    /* 
        this function returns the currency with position selected in currency settings 
    */
    function fetch_currency_with_symbol($amount,$currency = '')
    {
        $amt_display = '';
        if($amount==''){ $amount =0; }
        $decimals=get_option('tmpl_price_num_decimals');
        $decimals=($decimals!='')?$decimals:2;
        if($amount >=0 )
        {
            if(@$amount !='')
                $amount = $amount;
                $currency = get_option('currency_symbol');
                $position = get_option('currency_pos');
            if($position == '1')
            {
                $amt_display = $currency.$amount;
            }
            else if($position == '2')
            {
                $amt_display = $currency.' '.$amount;
            }
            else if($position == '3')
            {
                $amt_display = $amount.$currency;
            }
            else
            {
                $amt_display = $amount.' '.$currency;
            }
            return apply_filters('tmpl_price_format',$amt_display,$amount,$currency);
        }
    }

    /* eof - display currency with position */

    /*  this function will display the legends descr
```

Comment: See if the help docs solve your problem http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F